# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given

Tags: mysql, parameters, resources

I've looked at all the previous related answers to this and similar and can't find what I may have wrong - I have similar in the same php and all work as expected. The code I have is:

```
$boomi=mysql_query("SELECT round(boomi.dspeed/func.min_line_speed *100, 0) 
AS diff  FROM func INNER JOIN boomi ON func.service_id=boomi.service_id         
WHERE func.min_line_speed > boomi.dspeed AND boomi.sync='Yes' 
AND func.service_id=%s", SQLVal($service_id, "int"));

$diff = mysql_result($boomi, 0,'diff');
```

There is a second error suggesting parameter 1 in the result ($diff) IS NULL

Comment: mysql_*  function are deprecated use mysqli_* functions instead

Comment: We will update, but its a huge amount of changes to be made - for another day...